# A Company of Thirteen #3

Tags: pattern, word-property

The following thirteen words have a special property common to all of them (though they're not the only words with this property):

> SADIST, THOROUGHFARE, HYMN, POISED, YURT, THIRTY-SEVEN, STREWN, VERTICALITY, INERTIA, BALDERDASH, HIGHFLYING, REWARDING, OPINIONATED

Firstly, what is this property? Secondly, which two words in the list have the property *more* than the other eleven?

Hint:

> the idea behind this puzzle also appears in another puzzle posted in the last few days, although that one is less enigmatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of them

> contains a string of at least 3 that's consecutive in the word and forms a connected block on a QWERTY keyboard: SADIST => SAD, THOROUGHFARE => UGHF, HYMN => HYMN, POISED => POI/SED, YURT => YURT, THIRTY-SEVEN => RTY, STREWN => REW, VERTICALITY => ERT, INERTIA => ERT, BALDERDASH => DERDAS, HIGHFLYING => GHF, REWARDING => REWA, OPINIONATED => OPI.

Two of them have

> two such strings that don't overlap: POISED has POI and SED, and BALDERDASH has DER and DAS (the latter two are contiguous but don't overlap).

Comment: Well done! I was thinking of, more specifically, a connected *horizontal* block (the trick with HYMN being that the comma is included!), so that the two which have the property more than others are YURT and STREWN. But you get my +1 and accept anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

So here is my "better answer", rescued from a close idea...

> all the words have a consecutive letters that are horizontally adjacent on the QWERTY keyboard:
>  **SA**DIST
>  THOROU**GH**FA**RE**
>  HY**MN**
>  **POI**SED
>  **YU** **RT**
>  THI**RTY**-SEVEN
>  S**TREW**N
>  V**ERT**ICALI**TY**
>  IN**ERT**IA
>  BALD**ER**D**AS**H
>  HI**GH**FLYING
>  **REW**ARDING
>  **OP**IN**IO**NATED

and the winning two then are

> STREWN and VERTICALITY

---

---

And here, for reference, is the acknowledged "weak answer" I tried first:

> The words all use at least two letters from the word "THIRTEEN".

And finding words that are more so than the others...

> Clearly THIRTY-SEVEN is the winner, using all 8 letters, but VERTICALITY and INERTIA can each source 5 of their letters from THIRTEEN (not counting letters more times that they appear there), so I actually end up with three words "better" than the others.

Comment: That's not a very special property - almost all the words in English have that property! Out of interest, what was your "something better"? It could be that a variant of that is the answer.

Comment: @randal'thor Having adjacent letters that are also adjacent in the alphabet.

Comment: That's not too far off actually...

Comment: "HYMN," was very sneaky - I would have gone for the three-block if not for that.

Comment: Hang on - you edited in the second answer before histocrat answered? How come I didn't notice?? I'm not sure which to accept now - you got the right idea first, but histocrat got a version of the right idea which was closer to the intended solution!

Comment: No worries. I was first on the page with this, but histocrat answered independently I'm sure (based on improving my initial thought in comments, probably).